# Looking into app folders inside iPhone device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Is there any way I can see the folder stricture for my app inside iPhone? I have installed a app in my iPhone and have dumped a file inside documents directory. I wanted to see what all data I have in this folder. Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the Xcode organizer.

[image]

Comment: I am using XCODE 3.2.6 and I am not able to see the drop down option in DEVICES inside Organizer. Do I need to switch to XCODE 4.0 for this?

Comment: This is possible in Xcode3 too. Select your device and in the bottom part of the screen there should be an area labeled "Applications". Search for your app, click the little triangle in front of the name and then drag&drop "Application Data" wherever you want, or use the download arrow at the end of the line.